# SetupIntent not attaching payment_method to customer

Tags: node.js, reactjs, stripe-payments

So I'm trying to update a users payment_method and attach it to a customer so that a user can continue to pay their recurring subscription. I'm doing this using SetupIntents

Node

```
const intent =  await stripe.setupIntents.create({
    customer: customer_id,
  });
response.send(intent.client_secret);
```

React

```
const result = await stripe.confirmCardSetup(client_secret, {
      payment_method: {
        card: elements.getElement(CardElement),
        billing_details: {
          email: email,
        },
      }
    });
    
    if (result.error) {
      // Display result.error.message in your UI.
    } else {
        // The setup has succeeded. Display a success message and send
        // result.setupIntent.payment_method to your server to save the
        // card to a Customer
    }
```

This does succeed but if I try to set invoice_settings.default_payment_method, on the Customer to the PaymentMethod’s ID

```
const customer = await stripe.customers.update(
  customer_id,
  {invoice_settings: {default_payment_method: payment_method}}
```

I get the error:

```
StripeInvalidRequestError: The customer does not have a payment method with the ID pm_1HelzAB9lEAzymezFB8ZvHek. The payment method must be attached to the customer.
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Did you manage to resolve this?

Comment: I just attached the payment method manually after I got the result.setupIntent.payment_method from confirmCardSetup.

Comment: thanks. I already solved my problem, I was accidentally using different customers when creating the SetupIntent and in later processing. The manual attachment was not necessary in my case, and it shouldn't be after confirmCardSetup, according to the docs. I was just setting up the wrong customer. Glad to hear you solved your problem as well :)

Comment: Awesome. I'm glad you figured it out.